# Takind a value from linked list in C#

Tags: c#, linked-list, media-player

I'm new for coding in C#. I'am making a media player which contains many functions.
While a video loading a text file which is prepared special for the video will be loading to a linked list. But in the txt file each line contains event_id, time(a function start time), Event (Open/Close), Channel, duration and parameter. The link below shows an example of a text file:

http://m1307.hizliresim.com/1c/b/q30qj.png

with this i'm adding all line as an item to a linked list:

```
    foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("Kod Yazmayı Öğrenmek.txt"))
    {
        linked.AddLast(line);
    }
```

with this i'm split each line with ",":

```
foreach (var item in linked)
        {
            string[] parts = item.Split(',');
        }
```

At this point i want to compare the media player's currentposition to the time in the linked list.

I tried to do this with arrays:

```
int size_linked = linked.Count();
        int offff = 1;
        int s = 0;
        foreach (var item in linked)
        {
            string[] parts = item.Split(',');
            my_array2[s] = parts[offff];
            offff += 6;
            s++;
        }
```

And i use this array in a method:

```
private void check()
    {
        int size_linked = linked.Count();
        for (int i = 0; i < size_linked; i++)
        {
            if (player.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition == Convert.ToDouble(my_array2[i]))
            {
                //  I will add function here 
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. How can i take time fron linked list that contains more than one value?

Thanks! :)

Comment: My full code is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dBhTnyCWz8uCdbON3Un-IKGOVeBp7OQTLXV9BDdq8aI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you split a string, you need to increase counter by 1 every loop instead of six 6.
i think that this can be enought:

```
int size_linked = linked.Count();
        int offff = 1;
        int s = 0;
        foreach (var item in linked)
        {
            string[] parts = item.Split(',');
            my_array2[s] = parts[offff];
            //if you want to take only first splitted string for every parts you comment this:
            //offff += 6;
            s++;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but i still have problems.
My  project leader said the problem could occurs on comparing floating numbers.
Then i create a new method:

    
        public static bool Between(double num, double lower, double upper)
        {
            if (lower <= num && num <= upper)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

Comment: then i compare with an epsilon. My new check metod is:

    private void check()
        {
            int size_linked = linked.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < size_linked; i++)
            {
                bool betweenresult = Between(player.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition, Convert.ToDouble(my_array2[i]) - 100, Convert.ToDouble(my_array2[i]) + 100);
                if (betweenresult)
                {
                    //  I will add function here 
                    MessageBox.Show("Time is : " + Convert.ToDouble(my_array2[i]));
                }
            }
        }

Comment: What's the my_array2 type?

Comment: string[] my_array2 = new string[100];

Comment: full code:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dBhTnyCWz8uCdbON3Un-IKGOVeBp7OQTLXV9BDdq8aI/edit

Comment: Can you write the stack trace?